# Incrementar mesmo se apagar registro

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho a função a seguir:

```
public function codigo_denuncia() {         
    $db = new mysql();

    //pegar as linhas do ano
    $ultimoRegisto = $db->executar("SELECT id FROM denuncia WHERE ano=year(now()) ");   

    //verifica se tem registro no ano 
    //se igual ao ano atual, incrementa, se não começa novamente com valor 1
        if($ultimoRegisto->num_rows > 0){
        return $ultimoRegisto->num_rows +1 . '-' . date('Y');
    }

    return 1 . '-' . date('Y');
}
```

A princípio funcionou OK, incrementando sempre corretamente, o problema ocorre se por ventura precisar apagar um registro aleatório dessa tabela, ele iria gerar o próximo número com registro duplicado, por exemplo tenho 40 registro e insiro mais um, o próximo código seria 41-2017, depois apago um registro da tabela e insiro outro novamente, ele iria gerar o mesmo código 41-2017. Alguma alternativa viável para essa função?
Foi feito com PHP e mysql e a chamada é a seguinte:

```
$codigo = $this->codigo_denuncia();
$arraycodigo = explode("-", $codigo);
$numero_denuncia = $arraycodigo[0].'/'.$arraycodigo[1];
```

Comment: mostra o código como eliminas o registo, ou é mesmo pelo mysql ?

Comment: É via função com caixa de seleção, se a caixa está selecionada ele apaga o ID respectivo da tabela.

Comment: Você deveria persistir esse código no banco se for possível... Na hora de inserir a denuncia, você contaria a quantidade de registros naquele ano e adicionaria em uma coluna de denuncia, tudo através de um insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas a pegar o numero de registos existentes e somando mais um é por isso que ele duplica, quando removes um registo

Para corrigir tenta fazer desta forma, pega o **id** do ultimo registo e soma mais um:

```
 public function codigo_denuncia() {         
    $db = new mysql();

    //pegar as linhas do ano
    $ultimoRegisto = $db->executar("SELECT id FROM denuncia WHERE ano=year(now()) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); 
    $row = $ultimoRegisto->fetch_assoc();

    //verifica se tem registro no ano 
    //se igual ao ano atual, incrementa, se não começa novamente com valor 1
    if($ultimoRegisto->num_rows > 0){

        return $row['id'] + 1 . '-' . date('Y');
    }

    return 1 . '-' . date('Y');
}
```

Comment: Era realmente isso, obrigado!